# Using JWT Authentication in spring boot but failed to login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

2024-02-29T12:22:12.726+05:30 ERROR 3552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter] with root cause

2024-02-29T12:22:12.735+05:30 DEBUG 3552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error2024-02-29T12:22:12.735+05:30 DEBUG 3552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
@Autowired
private JwtTokenHelper jwtTokenHelper;
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String requestToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    String username = null;
    String token = null;
    if (requestToken != null && requestToken.startsWith("Bearer")) {
         token = requestToken.substring(7);
         try{username=this.jwtTokenHelper.getUsernameFromToken(token);}
         catch (IllegalArgumentException e){System.out.println("Unable to get jwt token");}
         catch(ExpiredJwtException e){System.out.println("Jwt token has expired");}
         catch (MalformedJwtException e){System.out.println("Invalid jwt");}
    }
    else{System.out.println(" Jwt token does not begin with Bearer");}

    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()==null){
        UserDetails userDetails =this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if(this.jwtTokenHelper.validateToken(token,userDetails)){
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid jwt");
        }
    }
    else{

    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
}}
```

Auth controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/auth")
public class AuthController {
@Autowired
private JwtTokenHelper jwtTokenHelper;
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
@Autowired
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<JwtAuthResponse> createToken(@RequestBody JwtAuthRequest request) throws Exception{
    this.authenticate(request.getUsername(),request.getPassword());
    UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(request.getUsername());
    String token = this.jwtTokenHelper.generateToken(userDetails);
    JwtAuthResponse response = new JwtAuthResponse();
    response.setToken(token);
    return new ResponseEntity<JwtAuthResponse>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}

private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws  Exception{
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password);
   try{
       authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
   }catch (BadCredentialsException e){
       System.out.println("Invalid Details");
       throw new ApiException("Invalid Username or Password");
   }
}

@PostMapping("/register")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> regidterUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto){
    UserDto registerdUser = this.userService.registerNewUser(userDto);
    return new ResponseEntity<UserDto>(registerdUser,HttpStatus.CREATED);
}}
```

config files

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {
@Autowired
UserRepo userRepo;
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    return provider;
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService() {
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
            return userRepo.findByEmail(username).orElseThrow(()-> new ResourceNotFoundException("User","email:"+username,0));
        }
    };
}
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration builder) throws Exception {
    return builder.getAuthenticationManager();
}}
```

security config

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 @EnableWebMvc
public class SecurityConfig{

public static final String[] PUBLIC_URLS={
        "api/v1/auth/**",
        "/v3/api-docs",
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/swagger-ui/**",
        "/webjars/**"

};

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

@Bean
protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz)-> authz
            .requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated())
            .exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(this.jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint))
            .sessionManagement(session->session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

   http
           .addFilterBefore( this.jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

   return http.build();
}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception)

Comment: No my question is when i am login through email and password which is already stored in my database so when i fire the request to login it says unauthorized in postman api but for register api it is working i went through my code i feel something wrong is in my code which i could not get it. maybe it does not get email

Comment: This type of authentication is not recommended there has been an active choice by spring security to not have this. Handing out jwts to browsers is dangerous, dont use jwts as sessions.

Answer (score 0):

add these dependencies to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This does not help as it lead to create the problem regarding the creation of bean and jparepository throws problem